# UTF-8 Character lost in JAVA

Tags: java, utf-8, iso, stringbuffer

I've got a problem with this code, I'm loosing the ° character :

```
StringBuffer libelle = new StringBuffer("Name : ");
libelle.append(lCurrentLine[2]);

try {
    libelle.append(new String(" - N° : ".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    libelle.append(" - N : ");
}
```

After this code I have `Name : blabla - NÂ° : blabla` in my StringBuffer instead of `Name : blabla - N° : blabla`

Any idea ?

Comment: what is the java file encoding?

Comment: you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Comment: You having utf encoded string and pass it to method that want ISO-8859-1 what else do you expect? What you want to achieve?

Comment: Not sure why but `.getBytes("UTF-16BE")` works.

Comment: It's unclear what you are attempting to do. Java's text datatypes use UTF-16. Both UTF-16 and UTF-8 are character encodings for the Unicode character set.  UTF-8 would only come into play when transferring text in a String to/from a file or stream.

Comment: `Â°` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `°` when interpretted as ISO-8859-1 instead of as UTF-8.  Just like you asked it to. But why are you encoding the appended string at all?  Why not just append it as-is? `libelle.append(" - N° : ");` What is the reason for encoding? What are you planning on doing with the `StringBuffer` after it is built up? Why do you need it encoded in ISO-8859-1? I think you should be handling that encoding at a different layer of your code, if at all.